# Pros and cons of threading text frames over columns in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, typography, workflow

I've recently learnt about threading text as frames and started using it - but when would it be better than a text column or table?

I understand you'd use columns for something like newspaper paragraphs, but threading text for adverts?

I've been creating test files to learn and understand this from tutorials online.

What are the pros and cons of all three approaches, for an advertisement, but also any InDesign file?

Comment: Do you have a visual example? (given some ads can be sponsored content that looks similar to articles)

Comment: Welcome Blackwood! For single pages, there's generally not a whole lot of benefit to text threading. Threading is really a multi-page thing. (I removed the version/OS sentence because it was irrelevant and won't have any bearing on answers — which is good and how we prefer questions to be formatted. `:)`)

Answer (score 0):

When I work on a project, I try to anticipate what revisions I might have to make and whether having running text will make edits easier or not. For example, if I have an ad with product shots anchored into text and I know that a product might be added or removed and I want the content to flow when I make a change, I might lay out multiple threaded columns or frames.

Other times, threading makes edits more difficult because I have already determined a placement of something, and edits may cause text to flow and push content out of the frame. For example, if I have a chart that I know should sit on the bottom of the page, then I don’t need to include it in a thread.

Sometimes you don’t know which is the better option, but you can always change your mind and decide to thread frames together (click outport of box, click on next box). Or unthread frames while keeping the content in the box (use the SplitStory script: Windows > Utilities > Scripts). After you have made enough revisions, it will become more apparent which option is best.